# ファイル中の座標の処理

Tags: ruby

下記のような座標を持つファイルをrubyで処理したいのですが、どのようにしたらいいか検討がつかず頓挫しています。アイデアを頂けますか。

処理前

```
group   start   end id  distance    value1  value2
A   5817    7756    id1 1939    0   3
A   5817    7754    id2 1937    -2  1
A   5817    7752    id3 1935    -4  1
A   5817    7747    id4 1930    -9  1
A   5817    10699   id5 1938    -50 1
A   5819    7756    id6 1937    -2  1
A   5819    7755    id7 1936    -3  1
A   5828    7756    id8 1928    -11 1
A   5983    8180    id9 2197    1   2
A   5983    8175    id10    2192    -5  2
A   5983    8174    id11    2191    -6  1
A   5984    8175    id12    2191    -6  1
```

上記のような重なりを持つ座標に関して、例として

```
(id2;end – id1;end) – (id2;start – id1;start) = id2;value1
(id3;end – id1;end) – (id3;start – id1;start) = id3;value1
```

というような条件を満たせば、id1とid2及びid3は同じグループに所属するとみなし、グループ内で一番大きいvalue1を持つid1のvalue2にそのカウントを足していきたいのです。

処理後

```
group   start   end id  length  value1  value2
A   5817    7756    id1 1939    0   9
A   5817    10699   id5 1938    -50 1
A   5983    8180    id9 2197    1   5
```

以上、ご教示の程、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: このファイルの中身は半角スペースの連続によって区切られているということで良いですか？

Comment: harry0000様　タブ区切りです。結局、行間の計算方法と、グループ分けの仕方が理解できていないのが頓挫している主な原因と考えています。宜しくお願いいたします。それから、id5の行のdistance値はタイプミスです。正しくは4882です。また処理後の例のこの項目がlengthになっていますが、distanceの間違えです。

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'pp'

list = []
open('/tmp/hoge.txt').read.split("\n").select.with_index{|a,i| i != 0}.map{|a| a.split(" ")}.map do |a|
  list << {
    group: a[0],
    start: a[1].to_i,
    end: a[2].to_i,
    id: a[3],
    distance: a[4].to_i,
    value1: a[5].to_i,
    value2: a[6].to_i
  }
end

id_comb_list = list.map{|a| a[:id]}.combination(3).to_a
id_comb_list.each do |ic|
  id1 = list.find{|a| a[:id] == ic[0]}
  id2 = list.find{|a| a[:id] == ic[1]}
  id3 = list.find{|a| a[:id] == ic[2]}
  if ( (id2[:end] - id1[:end]) - (id2[:start] - id1[:start]) == id2[:value1] ) &&
     ( (id3[:end] - id1[:end]) - (id3[:start] - id1[:start]) == id3[:value1] )
    target = [id1, id2, id3].sort_by{|c| c[:value1]}.last
    target[:value2] += target[:value1]
  end
end

pp list
```